# Bulk Insert instead of foreach loop: Laravel 5.2.31

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using the following code to insert the records One by One.

```
foreach($data["SportsTypes"] as $SportsTypeID) {
    $userSportsType = new \App\Models\User\UserSportsTypeModel();
    $userSportsType->UserID       = 1;
    $userSportsType->SportsTypeID = $SportsTypeID;
    $userSportsType->save();
}
```

Can I do bulk insert so as to get rid of saving process in iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You must use **foreach** to insert multiple models or use **Query Builder** instead.

A few people requested that but Tayler Otwell suggested to use **Query Builder** in these cases. [Reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295)

**Query Builder**

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```

[Documentation for insert method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts)

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to do a bulk insert in Laravel using Eloquent or the query builder.

You can use the following approach.

```
$data = array(
    ['UserID' => '1', 'SportsTypeID' => $SportsTypeID],
    ['UserID' => '2', 'SportsTypeID' => $SportsTypeID]
);

User::insert($data); // Eloquent
DB::table('users')->insert($data); // Query Builder
```

Hope this will help.